# How to correctly change style in *ngFor Items?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ngfor

So I am using *ngFor in a component's HTML file to make quick interfaces for a recipe in a food app. I have a problem though. You see, when it's time to change key properties such as a background-image with a CSS property of url() change, I'm having a difficulty when it comes to applying those styles that involve dynamic name changes. (the recipe names in the *ngFor directive inside my HTML template.) These names vary.

Additionally, I'm retrieving this information from my component's ts file which is linked to a service where the JSON format array of objects is located.

I'm accessing these properties through dot notation for simple changes with a template like

```
<h1>{{recipe.recipeName}}</h1>
```

I'm trying to have a picture right under that header that matches the ones I have in my images folder (already downloaded) so I've tried something like...

```
 style.backgroundImage="{{'url(../../../imgs/food/startRecipes/' + **recipe.recipeName** +'.jpg)'}}"
```

which simply resulted in giving me errors in finding my files (where I know for a fact exist!)
I get the 404 ERROR...

```
http://localhost:4200/imgs/food/guacamole.jpg **404 (Not Found)**
```

I also have some recipes in the JSON array that have a space in their name, and I cannot find a simple way to remove them... I tried using the replace method (I come from learning JavaScript) but it didn't quite work either.

Do you have any recommendations? I'm truly lost here. I'm still studying Angular, and I haven't quite caught up with pipes section in the course yet. However, I'm sure there's a much simpler way to do it in this case, maybe a ngStyle method, or something like that! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: wheres your imgs folder located ? is it same as src

Comment: No,It's a sibling of the app folder (child of src.) I am 100% sure the path is correct

Comment: What happens if you put http://localhost:4200/imgs/food/guacamole.jpg in the address bar?

Comment: The very same page reloads as if I hadn't change the route path. Keep in mind I don't have any route paths preset anywhere though. @AdrianBrand

Comment: Routes don't affect assets, try using the assets folder, that is what it is for.

Comment: put your images in assets folder and  use something like `url(assets/imgs/food/startRecipes/someimage.jpg)`

Comment: Right, but how exactly do I add the dynamic name? like I do in the example? Because even If I put the images in the assets folder, it's not rendering it correctly... Dumps the same 404 error

Comment: I ended up implementing jQuery in my app and selecting the containers created by the ngFor through the AfterViewInit lifecycle so it could correctly retrieve and append. Not the best solution, but it does the trick for now until I learn how to change those types of properties dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `angular-cli.json` and look for something like this

```
{
"apps": [{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "imgs",
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
}]
}
```

By adding the `imgs` folder name in the list of assets, you'll tell angular that it should look into the imgs folder for assets too for non routable Get requests. Otherwise the folder is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, in this case, this didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting a 404 Error...

Comment: I ended up implementing jQuery in my app and selecting the containers created by the ngFor through the AfterViewInit lifecycle so it could correctly retrieve and append. Not the best solution, but it does the trick for now until I learn how to change those types of properties dynamically. In any way, thanks for the help, I learned something new!